# CanCan Link Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Currently my navigation partial is as given below.

```
- if (can? :manage, Invoice) and (can? :manage, InvoiceItem)
  %li{class: is_active?(["invoices", "invoice_items"])}
    = link_to invoices_path do
      %i.icon-file-text
      Invoices
```

I see that the can method that define ability can accept an array. Is there a way to make the can? helper method more concise?

**UPDATE**: I have written a small application helper to sort this out. Is this the best way?

```
def user_can?(actions, resources)
  actions.each do |action|
    resources.each do |resource|
      return false if cannot? action, resource
    end
  end
  true
end
```

And in the partial:

```
- if user_can? [:manage], [Invoice, InvoiceItem]
  %li{class: is_active?(["invoices", "invoice_items"])}
    = link_to invoices_path do
      %i.icon-file-text
      Invoices
```

Comment: checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446654/how-do-i-use-cancan-to-authorize-an-array-of-resources

Comment: That's for defining the ability, right? I was hoping something for view helper method. I may end up writing one, but thought of checking before doing that.

Comment: Your own solution to this looks good. If you were just looking for something to tidy up your views and that looks like it would do the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`can?` only evaluates one action and one resource at a time as you noted.  Your helper is fine, assuming that you don't need to check different combinations of actions and resources, which you typically don't do in a single conditional statement in a view.

You probably also want to consider why you really need to check for `:manage` access to `InvoiceItem` when deciding whether to display a list of `Invoice`s.

Comment: There are two reasons I have to do this. One, though I use nested resource for Invoice Item, but I keep invoice item selection in a separate page (like a wizard workflow) and a controller to support that. Second, the menu is grouped (such as Transactions and Masters) and this would be required there too. There would be too many can? calls when the user clicks on a page. That's what I wanted to reduce, if it was possible.